# How to convert Count 0 values in blanks

Tags: reporting-services

I have a matrix in SSRS with projects in different stages. I'm counting the number of projects in a certain stage. When there are no projects in a stage ssrs gives a 0 value.

How can I get ssrs to make blanks of that zero value?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your number format string value to #

[image]